# How to deserialize date in JSON string

Tags: .net, json, serialization, f#, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON string:

```
{
    "id":"4711363275",
    "owner":"51262181@N07",
    "datetaken":"2010-06-10 11:34:35",
    "ownername":"tlamy",
    "latitude":48.85959,
    "longitude":2.291872
}
```

Following is the F# code:

```
[<DataContract>]
type photo = {
        [<field: DataMember(Name = "id")>]
        photo_id:int64
        [<field: DataMember(Name = "owner")>]
        owner:string
        [<field: DataMember(Name = "datetaken")>]
        datetaken:DateTime
        [<field: DataMember(Name = "latitude")>]
        latitude:float
        [<field: DataMember(Name = "longitude")>]
        longitude:float
}

let internal unjson<'t> (jsonString:string)  : 't =  
    use ms = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonString)) 
    let obj = (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).ReadObject(ms) 
    obj :?> 't
let decodePhoto = unjson<photo>
```

The issue I am having is with the date field, the code above throws a deserializing error. How can I specify the format of the date string to parse?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check out : http://musingsfromacube.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but can you use [IDeserializationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx) interface or the [OnDeserializing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx) attribute for this?